# How to restrict "web.xml" being called in URL (Servlet)?

Tags: java, url, servlets, web.xml, servlet-filters

How to restrict "web.xml" being called in URL ?

for example:

```
 "http://localhost:8080/myapp/web.xml"
```

When i make request like this then blank page will be displayed and response status is 200 OK.
And when i trying to catch this url in my custom "Filter" then the request will not comes to the filter only for this request.

if you make a request to some other xml like

```
  "http://localhost:8080/myapp/test.xml"
```

then the request will come to my custom Filter.

My custom filter mapping is in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SecureRequestResponseFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>package.path.SecureRequestResponseFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecureRequestResponseFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is your filter mapping?

Comment: @JunedAhsan, in my customer filter i just trying to check url ends with "web.xml". but the request itself is not coming to filter.

Comment: That's why i asked your web.xml filter mapping

Comment: @JunedAhsan, i have edited my question and added web.xml filter mapping. thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? web.xml file is in the WEB-INF folder which is not accessible from the browser, so no one will load it via URL. There is no `/myapp/web.xml` resource, so probably your filter is called, but it cannot find the resource and generates some exception and generates blank page. Hard to tell without seeing your filter.

Comment: @Gas, I am agree with your first line comment about web.xml in "web-inf" folder. But my filter does not called. I added debugger and tested it. It will work for all other request but not to "web.xml" and it shows black page and response is 200 OK.
thanks.

Comment: @user3515080 Try to invoke other non existing file like `/myapp/blabla.xml` and see what happens. What container are you using? I don't observe similar behavior, so there must be some problem in your env. Add full code of your filter and web.xml

Comment: Do you have a blank file called web.xml directly under /myapp/? And what is the filter supposed to do?

Comment: @developerwjk. No, i don't have any blank file in web.xml. And i write the filter only for this, but the filter will not be called in time of this request.